# SSRS 2008 Report deployment to server hides a field

Tags: deployment, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

When I deploy one of the reports I've made to the report server, a field that is shown when I preview in SSRS magically disappears. I've re-downloaded the report from the report server and opened it up in SSRS and the field reappears when I preview.

Has anyone encountered something like this?

I've tried searching for similar problems but nothing came up.

Please & thanks.

Comment: Is this a control on the body of the report that's not showing up, or a parameter?

Comment: check the visibility of the column.

Comment: Whoops, thanks for the comments, I could have sworn I was tracking this topic. It is a control on the body of the report that isn't showing up. It's not related to the column since there is data above and below this row in question.

Answer (score 0):

For a long time I have always deleted the report from the server prior to deployment when I change /Datasource/Parameters values---works for me. Then re-deploy and you should be set.

Comment: I have already tried deleting and re-deploying the report, thanks though!